# I'm uploading an image with react native and post it an API. It only works in my second try

Tags: android, react-native, httprequest, fetch-api, react-native-image-picker

I'm using react native class component. I'm trying to pick an image from gallery and post it to API. But it only works in my second try.

When I pick image from gallery it says:

> Fetch Error: [Type error: Network request failed].

I got 'success' alert at my second request, but never works on first try. Here is some parts of my code:

```
openImagePicker = () => {
    const options = {
      mediaType: 'photo',
    };

    launchImageLibrary(options, async (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('Image picker error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        console.log('Image picker Worked: ', response.message);

        let imageUri = response.uri || response.assets?.[0]?.uri;
        let fileType = response.type || 'image/jpeg'; 
        let fileName = response.fileName || 'image.jpg';

        this.setState({ files: imageUri },
          () => { console.log('files138:', this.state.files) }
        );

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('files', {
          uri: imageUri,
          type: fileType,
          name: fileName,
        });

        fetch(config.restApi+'upload/advert/tr', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + clientData.sessionHash
          },
          body: formData,
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(responseData => {
            switch (responseData.status) {
              case 200: {
                Alert.alert('Success');
              }
                break;
              case 203: {
                Alert.alert('203');
              }
                break;
              default: {
                Alert.alert('Alert Error');
              }
                break;
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Fetch error:', error);
          });
      }
    });
  };

case 3:

        return (

          <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            {this.state.files && (
              <Image
                source={{ uri: this.state.files }}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            )}
            <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              <Button title="Choose from Device" onPress={this.openImagePicker} />
            </View>
          </View>

        );
```

Comment: Which status code were returned at the first request ?